# Options for offline/local storage without a database for javascript app

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, offline, html5-filesystem

Here is my scenario:

I am familiar with Javascript and would like to create some simple apps to use at work either personally or as proofs of concepts to present before taking them further and getting actual web server space. I do not however want to setup an actual database on my machine. I would prefer, if possible, to read/write to a local JSON file. This is where I am a bit stuck as most of my queries have turned up old information prior to the html 5 FileSystem API or Node.js (already installed on my machine) or whatever else there may be now.

Does anyone know of a tutorial for creating an offline MVP with database-less storage or something similar? Or just general advice on what to look at to get started?

I have been reading the HTML 5 Filesystem API and Node.js FS stuff but without an example I am finding it quite difficult to know where to begin.

Comment: You prefer a storage on client-side or server-side ?

Comment: @kevpoccs client side as there will be no server

Comment: If you're looking for client-side storage, then node's `fs` module probbly isn't what you're looking for.  That's a server-side thing.

Comment: @teharron, Have you ever take a look at the Web SQL Database ?

Comment: @kevpoccs I followed a link to http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ once and was scared away by the banner saying they were no longer maintaining it. Is it worth checking out still?

Comment: @juanpaco thanks for the heads-up, wasn't sure if it would be of use or not since I wont be running node on a server.

Comment: @tehaaron Wow! I Haven't see this.. I've do some tests on an offline app last year, it do the job for keep some params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On **April 24th, 2014** the W3C officially matured the FileSystem API to a **[Working Group Note](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)** and development with this technology should be done with caution, not certain if or how long it'll stick around.

The [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) is looking to be a promising alternative/work-around, perhaps check out the [html5 rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) instead. Left my initial answer below because it is still valid, but wanted to leave a word of caution about the File-System API.

---

I see you got an answer but I wanted to give a solution to the file-system api (which you also asked about) With cookies you have a size limitation, but to answer the other side of your question the following is the [article I used to get started with the HTML5 File-system API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Everything else within the file-system api revolves around getting the reference to a file and then creating writers, readers, ect. specific for that file instance. Callback functions are passed/to be executed when file writers, readers, references have completed loading.

#### Requesting storage Quota/get a reference to the FileSystem

```
var onInitFs = function(fs){
    fileSystem = fs;//set global reference to the filesystem
};
var errorHandler = function(e){console.log('Error', e);};
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024*1024*5, function(grantedBytes) {
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 
}, errorHandler);
```

#### Making a file

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("filepathtoJSON", {
            create: true
}, callback, errorHandler);
```

#### Writing JSON to file

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("filepathtoJSON", {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
                writer.onwriteend = function(e){
                    callbackFunction();
                }
                writer.onerror = function(e3){console.log(e3);}
                var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(targetJSONobj)]);
                writer.write(blob);
            };
            writer.onerror = function(e3) {console.log(e3);};
            writer.truncate(0);
        }, errorHandler);
   }, errorHandler);
```

#### Reading JSON from a file/creating a fileReader(pass JSON object in a callback function)

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("filepathtoJSON", {creation:false}, function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function(file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
               callback(JSON.parse(this.result));
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, errorHandler)
    }, errorHandler);
```

Comment: FileSystem API appears to be 'dead' according to the blog post you have linked!

Comment: @ccanduc Thanks for letting me know! Though in my defense at the time of writing that wasn't the case and I don't feel it voids my answer (since the file-system api was in question), as that announcement was made less than a month ago and I posted 4 months ago. Your thoughts?
To confirm your comment - the Decision was [published April 24th, 2014](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) I'm not certain what this means for Chrome's implementation... looks like I'll be switching over to [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) - another persistent local storage technology that's still in spec.

Comment: I think it was a really valuable answer, especially considering that FileSystem API wasn't in question at the time of answer - I'd maybe suggest adding an update in bold at the top of the answer that links to the Decision - just personal opinion though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write it yourself by turning the object to a string and storing as a cookie or using local storage:

```
var data = { 'example': 324324 };
document.cookie = JSON.stringify(data);
var loaded = document.cookie.split(';');
console.log(JSON.parse(loaded [0]));
```

Or alternatively use a library which will do it for you!

http://brian.io/lawnchair/

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for and I am surprised at the simplicity. Lawnchair looks especially elegant. Thanks!

Comment: Cookies have limitation on size (4KB), so depending on how much you want to store, cookie storage may not be the right solution. Depending on the browser support requirements, look into local storage of stringified (i.e., JSON) data.